# con.txt and C++

Tags: c++, windows, fileoutputstream

```
#include <fstream>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   std::ofstream F("con.txt", std::ios::out);

   F << "some text in con.txt";

   F.close();

   return 0;
}
```

output:

```
some text in con.txt
```

If i replace "`con.txt`" with "`something.txt`" then something.txt will contains the string "`some text in something.txt`."

I think that the file con.txt bind with a console file...  What is real happened in the first case?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`CON` is a *reserved device name* on Windows platforms. It shouldn't be used as a file name, even with an extension.

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#naming_conventions):

> Do not use the following reserved
>   device names for the name of a file:
>   `CON`, `PRN`, `AUX`, `NUL`, `COM1`, `COM2`, `COM3`,
>   `COM4`, `COM5`, `COM6`, `COM7`, `COM8`, `COM9`,
>   `LPT1`, `LPT2`, `LPT3`, `LPT4`, `LPT5`, `LPT6`,
>   `LPT7`, `LPT8`, and `LPT9`. Also avoid these
>   names followed immediately by an
>   extension; for example, `NUL.txt` is not
>   recommended.

Comment: what if it is `ifstream` and user enters non-existing `con.txt`? `ifstream` otherwise will tell you that the file does not exist, but in this case it hangs to read from the console! The only fix is to first check if the file exists then open using `ifstream`, but that is extra checks that makes `ifstream` less useful.