# Java jdk1.8 file creation in windows 7

Tags: java, windows, io

I spent way too much time on a task as trivial as creating a file in the 
current working directory.

I tried both the `File.createNewFile()` way and the `Files.createFile()` way.
The latest code version is :

```
Path p= Paths.get(current_dir,confile);
if(!Files.exists(p))
{
  Files.createDirectories(p.getParent());
  Files.createFile(p);
}
```

and the exception thrown is :

```
Working dir F:\ProgCourse\java_projects\DBProject
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: F:\ProgCourse\java_projects\DBProject\con.txt
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:79)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:230)
    at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createFile(Files.java:632)
```

This folder `F:\ProgCourse\java_projects\DBProject\`
does exists and I own it and I have all the rights on it , I'm the administrator on the machine. And beside, NetBeans is already creating my 
projec files inside. I've even tested the path via cd command inside
console (cmd.exe) and it worked.
I can assure you that the path is valid from my point of view, I checked and 
it does exist. The question is what is java seeing as path and why java and the OS do not agree.
If such a trivial thing can suck up so much time then I don't know what I should realy do. I mean I'm realy disapointed about my skills, java, windows 7 . I mean wth !

Comment: Are you certain that's a local drive? Can you create `con.txt` with notepad in the folder?

Comment: Yes,it is, I have no mounted drives. And as I said I did tested it on cmd.exe.

Comment: You tested that you can cd there... did you test that you can write there?

Comment: According to the stacktrace, the problem is that the file "con.txt"doesn't exist (i. e. it doesn't complain about the directory but about a file that is expected to exist inside your dir) I'm just commenting this because you are mentioning the dir, not the file

Comment: can u try this Path parentDir = project.getFilePath().getParent();

Comment: See my answer below. On createFile - NoSuchFileException should only mean invalid path.

Comment: Yes it is but  how was I to know to search for " con.* "?That's almost one step away from not having the problem in the 1st time.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. So I soved it. This is incredible at least from me.
At least I'm glad I'm not the problem.
This is what Notepad++ shows on my 1st name attempt: [pic](http://postimg.org/image/g9hqsb0yf/)

And my 2nd attempt : [pic](http://postimg.org/image/ow0y83hwb/)

However "whatever.txt" can be created.

Credit should go to  Elliott Frisch for the idea to test with Notepad.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477368/con-txt-and-c ?

Comment: It's true but how was I to know to search for " con.* "?That's  almost one step away from not having the problem in the 1st time.

Comment: No sane software engineer would design an operating system that reserved particular file names appearing anywhere in any file system. Pure madness.