# FileStream output is being shown in Ostream C++

Tags: c++, file, file-handling

I have the following code and the `filestream` output is being displayed as `cout` to my command prompt.

I have read text from an input file and writing it in another file and `cout` a counter that shows how many files are processed. But there are some lines which is supposed to write in the file but instead of it it is printed on screen.

If there is "CON" word in the stream which is printing on file then this stream is printed on screen instead of file.

This is my output:

[image: This link is not supposed to show here]

The 17th line in console should not be there.

Comment: Please tell us what language you are using. The experts will not find he question to be able to answer without such details. Use the [edit] button to add information.

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The code block you've entered appears to be part of a larger whole (indenting, dangling curly brace at end).

Comment: Please refrain from editing code out of your question after solving the problem; instead, post your solution as an answer.  This will help anyone else that encounters the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

use of reseved keywords of windows as file name is detected

[con.txt and C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4477368/con-txt-and-c)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#naming_conventions